# Why do I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using %1$s for String(format:)

Tags: ios, swift, string, exc-bad-access

I have a `localized` `string` that looks like this:

```
String(format: "unable_to_reach".localized(), name) //name is a string. I have also tried just "x"
```

The `key/value` pair in the `localize` file looks like this:

```
"unable_to_reach" = "Unable to reach %1$s";
```

Now, *sometimes* this works, othertimes it crashes with the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Why is this? isn't %1$s supposed to be used for `string` values?

Comment: Why you did not use `%@` ( "Unable to reach %@")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format specifier `%1$s` is `%s` with a positional specifier of `$1` inserted into it. `%s` is the format specifier for a null-terminated C string. If you instead pass it a Swift String, bad things will happen. Don't do that. (It will likely cause a buffer overflow if the Swift string does not contain any null bytes.)

You want `%@` (or `%$1@`, to preserve the positional specifier.)

See the document on [**string format specifiers**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) for more information.

### Edit:

BTW, you should think about using Swift string interpolation instead:

```
let unableToReach = "unable_to_reach".localized()
let final = "\(unableToReach) \(name)"
```

That is more "Swifty".

Note that if you want to use localized placeholders to allow for different word ordering in different languages, you really still need to use `String(format:)` and the `%@` (or `%1@` positional syntax) version.

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thanks alot for you help :D